# How to initialize global variable android

Tags: java, android

I want to Initialize table Int[] y as the Global Variable where and how do this
Code for the Line Graph

```
public class LineGraph{
Context applicationContext;
Boolean Buttons;
Boolean Legend;
Boolean Grid;
public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    Buttons = prefs.getBoolean("view", true);
    Legend = prefs.getBoolean("legend", true);
    Grid = prefs.getBoolean("Grid", false);
    // Our first data
    int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
    int[] y =  { 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; // y values!
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1"); 
    for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        series.add(x[i], y[i]);
    }

    // Our second data
    int[] x2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
    int[] y2 =  { 145, 123, 111, 100, 89, 77, 57, 45, 34, 30}; // y values!
    TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries("Line2"); 
    for( int i = 0; i < x2.length; i++)
    {
        series2.add(x2[i], y2[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    dataset.addSeries(series2);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
    mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    if (Buttons==true){
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);}
    else{
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false); 
    }
    if (Legend==true){
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    }else{
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    }
    if (Grid==true){
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    }else{
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
    }
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 2
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

    // Customization time for line 1!
    renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    // Customization time for line 2!
    renderer2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent (context, GraphLoading.class);
    intent1.putExtra("SomeKey",x);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
    return intent;

}

}
```

And I want to that Table be visible by this class:

```
public class GraphLoading extends Activity {
    private LineGraph parent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    }
}
```

And I want to the GraphLoading can edit this table and the class LineGraph see changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create `static` object of this class.
For example:

```
public class LineGraph{
   public int Number;
   public LineGraph() {}
}
```

Then you should create static object of this class in any activity, for example `ExampleActivity`:

```
public static LineGraph LG = new LineGraph();
//then set some data to LG
LG.Number = 10;
```

Then you can use data from this clas in other activity:

```
int Test = ExampleActivity.LG.Number;
//We will have 10
```

Or **second way**. You can post data, using `Intent` (in `FirstPage` activity):

```
String str = "Test";
int num = 10;
int array[] = {1,2,3};
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstPage.this, SecondPage.class);
intent.putExtra("TEST_STRING", str);
intent.putExtra("TEST_INT", num);
intent.putExtra("TEST_INT_ARRAY", array);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in `SecondPage` activity you can get this data like this:

```
Intent sender = getIntent();
String some_str = sender.getExtras().getString("TEST_STRING");
int some_int = sender.getExtras().getInt("TEST_INT");
int[] some_int_array = sender.getExtras().getIntArray("TEST_INT_ARRAY");
```

Comment: Java has no support for top level static classes.  Only nested classes may be static.

Comment: @Simon Yes, you're right. I'll edit answer.

Comment: Thanks and can you add how do this with table int[]y (in first way).

Comment: @user2908626 Make 'int[] y' public out of 'getIntent()' method.  Create this class in SomeActivity, make render (set values to 'int[] y'). Then in some other activity int[] some_int_array = SomeActivity.LG.y;

Comment: Can you use this in my code (I am amateur...)

Comment: public class LineGraph{ /*...*/ public int[] y; /*...*/ public Intent getIntent(Context context) { /*...*/ y =  { 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; /*...*/ } then do like I wrote earlier.

Answer (score 0):

put this declaration between your boolean variables and getIntent function: `public static int[] y;` and remove the `int []` before y assignment. Now you can use the array y in every method and class of your package!

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int[] y` as a class variable (static field) and `public` so that it may be accessed in other classes in its package as well:

```
public class LineGraph {
    public static int[] y =  {30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111, 123, 145};
    Context applicationContext;
    // ...
```

---

Then reference it from your other class like this: `LineGraph.y`

Example:

```
public class GraphLoading extends Activity {
    private LineGraph parent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);

        int y[] = LineGraph.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2908626 Why not?

Comment: Can do this in not static field? I want to change the table y[] in the GraphLoadnig class and beacuse it is in the static field i cannot change it.

Comment: @user2908626 You can change a static field...

Comment: @user2908626 I need to tell you how to change it? I don't understand what you're asking, but here is an example I just made for you: http://pastie.org/8614888

Comment: I paste and edit your code but i have an error http://zapodaj.net/0c107eec569d9.png.html

Comment: @user2908626 it's saying you can't access `y` unless it's `static`. In my code, I made it static: `public static int[] y = ...` so you must have changed it.

Comment: but i want to edit it but when it is static i cant

Comment: @user2908626 Please, just try it. **YOU CAN CHANGE A STATIC FIELD**. However, you can't change a *final* variable. Just try it and look up what static means/does.